# Greater than selector not working

Tags: jquery, css, selector, parseint

I have a swipe-gesture enabled gallery. By swiping left / right, the user navigates the gallery. I need to limit the position of the sliding div so it doesn't go off track, i.e. once you've arrived on page, obviously all the images are to the right so I don't want users swiping left (to blank space).

I tried to use "greater than" but it's not working.

```
var theWidth = $(window).width();

function processingRoutine() {
    var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);

    if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
        $(".frame").animate({marginLeft: '-='+theWidth});
    } else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
        $(".frame").animate({marginLeft: '+='+theWidth});

        if ( parseInt($(".frame").css("margin-left")) > 1 ) {
            $(".frame").animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        }
    }
}
```

You can view the whole source here: http://joinersart.co.uk/mtest

Comment: I don't see where you are using the greater than selector... (in what is posted here)

Comment: `$(".frame").css("margin-left")` is coming out to `0px`.. you might have to remove the `px` from the returned string

Comment: @wirey he's using `parseInt()` so '0px' is fine, however he should be providing a radix. `parseInt('0px',10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a simple mistake:

I was confused about where margin-left should register the "no go" area. I had initially thought that if the margin-left was anything more than 1px that would be enough. In fact, it needs to be actually be minus the amount I was moving.

So instead of:

```
  if ( parseInt($(".frame").css("margin-left")) > 1 ){...
```

It should be:

```
   if ( parseInt($(".frame").css("margin-left")) > -theWidth ){...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(".frame").animate({margin-left: "0px"});
```

To:

```
$(".frame").animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my example page with your code but sadly no luck. http://joinersart.co.uk/mtest

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with `parseInt()`. because the value of margin-left can be '0px' `parseInt()` is going to use a radix of 8 i believe. (which is deprecated) If you use `parseInt(frame.css("margin-left"), 10)` that should parse your string into the correct integer value using a radix of 10 (decimal).

Comment: I don't see why that would be the issue. `0px` is still `0`, regardless of the radix it uses.